# "class has no constructors" error for class template

Tags: c++, insert, linked-list

I'm making a linked list, and I just want to add a node to the front of the list.  What am I doing wrong?

`Node.h`

```
 #pragma once

 namespace list_1
 {
template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node<T> *next;

    // Constructor
    // Postcondition: 
    Node<T> (T d);
};

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(T d)
{
    data = d;
    next = NULL;
}
 }
```

`list.h`

```
template <typename T>
void list<T>::insert_front(const T& entry)
{
    Node<T> *temp = head;

    if(temp == NULL)
        temp->next = new Node(entry);
    else
    {
        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
           temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp->next = new Node(entry);
    }
}
```

Error message;

```
 1>------ Build started: Project: Linked List, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
 1>  list_test.cpp
 1>c:\...\linked list\list.h(54): error C2955: 'list_1::Node' : use of class template requires template argument list
 1>          c:\...\linked list\node.h(7) : see declaration of 'list_1::Node'
 1>          c:\...\linked list\list.h(48) : while compiling class template member function 'void list_1::list<T>::insert_front(const T &)'
 1>          with
 1>          [
 1>              T=double
 1>          ]
 1>          c:\...\linked list\list_test.cpp(33) : see reference to class template instantiation 'list_1::list<T>' being compiled
 1>          with
 1>          [
 1>              T=double
 1>          ]
 1>c:\...\linked list\list.h(54): error C2514: 'list_1::Node' : class has no constructors
 1>          c:\...\linked list\node.h(7) : see declaration of 'list_1::Node'
 1>c:\...\linked list\list.h(62): error C2514: 'list_1::Node' : class has no constructors
 1>          c:\...\linked list\node.h(7) : see declaration of 'list_1::Node'
 ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: I don't suppose the core offending line (list_test.cpp:33) ant its surrounding code is available for posting here as well ? Also, Node appears to be in the `list_1` namespace in its header, but I see no such namespace wrapper in  `list.h` for the small snippet of code you chose to post from that file.

Comment: I think you need `new Node<T>(entry);`

Comment: Shouldn't things like `new Node(entry)` be `new Node<T>(entry)`?

Comment: You guys rock.. That fixed it.

Comment: @WhozCraig The error message tells you what's wrong.

Comment: I never really understood why compilers do this.  99% of the time, you only care about the *first* error message.  Everything following that is potentially meaningless since the first error may result in many more meaningless errors.  The point is -- focus on the first error message and ignore everything following that -- at least in your initial analysis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the error message:

> use of class template requires template argument list

`new Node(entry)` should be `new Node<T>(entry)`